# Streamlit webapp and https-portal configuration issues

Tags: docker-compose, https, streamlit

I have a Streamlit webapp on my test pc that I deployed with docker. The app is accessible online only on http. I wanted to use https so I found this docker image :https://hub.docker.com/r/steveltn/https-portal
It seems an easy way to enable https, but I didn't have any success.

Here is my docker-compose.yaml:

```
services:
  https-portal:
    image: steveltn/https-portal:1
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'
    links:
      - streamlit_app
    restart: always
    environment:
      WEBSOCKET: 'true'
      DOMAINS: 'http://example.go.ro/ -> http://streamlit_app:8501'
      STAGE: production # mantenha em staging até o total funcionamento
    volumes:
      - https-portal-data:/var/lib/https-portal
      
  streamlit_app:
    build:
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
      context: ./ 
    volumes:
      - .:/ETCWebApp
    ports:
      - 8501:8501
    restart: always
```

Using this config, I still only get http not https.

Update:
This is the error I am getting:

```
Failed to sign example.go.ro.
https-portal_1   | Make sure your DNS is configured correctly and is propagated to this host
https-portal_1   | machine. Sometimes that takes a while.
```

Answer (score 0):

It works with the folowing config:

```
services:
  streamlit_app:
    build:
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
      context: ./ 
    volumes:
      - .:/ETCWebApp
    ports:
      - 8501:8501
    restart: unless-stopped
    
  https-portal:
    image: steveltn/https-portal:1.22
    depends_on:
      - streamlit_app
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      WEBSOCKET: 'true'
      DOMAINS: 'example.go.ro -> streamlit_app:8501'
```

Also port forwarding between router and pc (80:80, 443:443)